# Why do some characters have Escape character before them?

Tags: character-encoding, escaping, sms, character, special-characters

Some special characters like | , ~ , ^ , { , }  and many others have Escape characters before them. Have a look at the screenshot or visit this link : http://messente.com/documentation/sms-length-calculator, to check it yourself.

I want to know as I don't understand why these characters have Escape characters before them or how/why these characters are different from other (special) characters.[image]

Comment: This is specifically about characters ***in SMS***? Please establish some explicit context here.

Comment: @deceze :  I am not sure if this is explicit only for SMS or is same in every case. After searching on internet  and doing some experiments myself, it seems this is only valid for SMS.But even for SMS why ?Adding more tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) for information about the GSM 03.38 encoding.

“Why” questions are always difficult to answer precisely, but my guess is that the goal is to be able to encode the characters deemed most common with 7 bits, while other, less frequent characters will require 14 bits.

There are only 1120 bits per SMS, so saving space is desirable. With the above encoding, you can get more than 140 characters encoded for a “normal” text message.